# Are these prepositional phrases adjectival or adverbial? "The little prince had very different ideas about serious things from those of the grown-ups"

Tags: sentence-structure

> The little prince had very different ideas about serious things from those of the grown-ups.

Are *about serious things* and *from those of the grown-ups* adjectival, which modify *ideas*?

Comment: No, ***about serious things*** modifies ***ideas***, but ***from those of the grown-ups*** modifies ***different***. Easier to see with *His ideas were very **different from** those of the grown-ups*. And I wouldn't say ***from those*** is "adjectival".

Comment: We know that you are reading _The Little Prince_, but you should still give the source of the quotation in your question.

Comment: "Serious things" is an NP functioning as complement of the prep "about". The whole PP "about serious things" is then complement of "ideas". The comparative complement is "from those of the grown-ups".

Comment: This is a translation from French and not the best way to ask per se about English. Also: "from those of the grown-ups" on its own is not grammatical at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'll summarise what @FumbleFingers commented on.

*about serious things* is adjectival and modifies *ideas*.

*from those of the grown-ups* modifies *different*.  We rephrase for clarity:

> his ideas were very **different** *from those of the grown-ups* [adverbial modifying *different*]

> he had ideas very **different** *from those of the grown-ups* [adverbial modifying *different*]

Comment: In my opinion, it would be more accurate to say that the prep phrase "about serious things" is complement (not modifier) of "ideas". It's a complement because it is licensed by the head, "ideas". The comparative complement,"from those of the grown-ups" is then complement of "different ideas about serious things".

Comment: [I will summarize//what FF commented **on**]

Comment: Compare the pseudo-cleft "[very different ideas about serious things from those of the grown-ups] was what the little prince had".